# Why set logging level for each module won't show logs in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Some simple codes to illustrate my question:

```
/src
   -- t1.py
   -- t2.py
   -- test.py
```

The test.py

```
import logging
import t1
import t2

def main():
    # I need to set logging level for each module, so can't call logging.basicConfig
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    t1.foo()
    t2.foo2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

t1.py

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def foo():
    logger.info('foo log message')
```

t2.py

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def foo2():
    logger.info('foo2 log message')
```

When I run `python3 test.py` I won't get logs. But if I call `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` in test.py I will get logs.

So what did I do wrong ?

--- update ---

What I can add to the answer I got is that the root logger's default level is 'WARNING'. So I did not get any output.

Comment: You could still use the `logging.basicConfig` in test.py to create a standard handler. `logger.setLevel` will work in the module files in addition to that.

Comment: @Wups Indeed!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) sets level of messages processable by this logger.

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` does [more than that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig). It creates a handler for the root logger which prints the logging records to stdout.

An example from the [cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations):

```
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

Comment: So you mean I also need to create handle in each module ?

Comment: Logging records propagate from the loggers in each module (in your case) to the parent loggers and in the end to the root logger. You need to add a handler to the root logger.  https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations

Comment: I mean, you could have added a handler to each logger, but usually it's enough to add one to the root logger.

Comment: Hi I am new to python logging, can you edit your answer to show how to get the root logger in test.py and add a handler to it in my codes ? Thanks!

Comment: So logging.getLogger('') to get the root logger. Thanks!